# Problem with OpenCV C++ Ubuntu 16.04-/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_*

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed OpenCV following http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/. Note that opencv_contrib are not installed. I had an error initially that opencv4.pc file was not found which I corrected by creating a new opencv4.pc in usr/local/lib and making appropriate changes in ~/.bashrc file. Now the error while compiling using c++ file from :
https://cv-tricks.com/installation/opencv-4-1-ubuntu18-04/.
This is the error I got:

[image: Error Received].

I tried to locate the missing files in other locations but I was unable to find them. Please help me solve my problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to install this version of OpenCV?

Comment: If running `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4` on the terminal doesn't work, don't bother using it as a part of your **g++** build command. Is there any reason for you not to use the `-I` (caps i), `-L` and `-l` (lowercase L) flags directly with their respective paths? It's nice to have **pkg-config** working but it's not mandatory.